# Nuget Command-line install is not launching Install/Init scripts

Tags: nuget, web-deployment, nuget-package, package-managers

I was trying to use **Nuget** as a software deployment system (repository, versioning and delivery) - idea from Octopus. Previously I was packaging ASP.NET sites into a self-extracting RAR archives with a .CMD startup scripts embeded. Now I'm trying to use Nuget creating puckages during automated build. The issue is that the package installation scripts (tools\Install.ps1 or tools\Init.ps1) do not execute if the package is being installed using command line:

```
nuget.exe install <package_id> -OutputDirectory <install_folder> -source <local_repo>
```

Same scripts are able to execute when package installed from Visual Studio Package Manager or Console.

I do not see why this shouldn't be possible given omnipresence of **PowerShell.**

Am I missing something or this is behaviour by design? Will appreciate you help.

Yes, we did consider **MSDeploy** but we already have install scripts that do the same thing and give more control and we need some strong package management and repository for build artifacts (something that Java folks do with Maven).

Comment: By 'do not execute', do you mean that the scripts are not being invoked, or that they fail during execution?

Comment: They are not being invoked at all

Answer (score 4):

As of today, the powershell scripts are not invoked from doing installations from command line.
One reason for this is that, in general, most of the install/init actions are tied to dte and the visual studio project and doesn't add much value to be able to run it from outside VS.

We have a backlog item for enabling support for exe based scripts too in addition to powershell.

Comment: Any progress on this ?